# Best method for mulit-file upload in Freeform?

Tags: solspace-freeform, file-uploads

Looking for advice on the best way to handle multiple file uploads associated with a Freeform entry.  We have a form that collects basic text-based demographic information, but it also requires several 4-5MB uploads.

I'd like to avoid asking users to zip into one file, but doing 4-5 http uploads seems dangerous.  Any great ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know FreeForm very well, but I bet this addon:

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-freeform-field

would work great with for allowing you to use a Matrix fieldtype (a purchased fieldtype, I don't work for them but it works pretty well) with a FreeForm form. You could probably use it to allow a single column Matrix fieldtype that user can expand on in the front-end; you'll need to do some work to make it all work but it smells like an answer to me.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like Low Freeform does exactly the opposite of what I'm looking for.  It brings Freeform data fields into channel entries.  It would be very useful to have the reverse.